Failed to resolve polars_core, arrow::legacy, Dataframe is polars-lazy = "0.44.2"
Despite the:

reading of the polar_lazy 0.44.2

sucessful installation of cargo add polars-lazy


the following code results in errors:

error[E0433]: failed to resolve: could not find legacy in arrow

error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared crate or module polars_core

error[E0412]: cannot find type PolarsResult in this scope

error[E0412]: cannot find type DataFrame in this scope
use polars_core::prelude::*;
use polars_core::df;
use polars_lazy::prelude::*;
use arrow::legacy::prelude::QuantileMethod;

fn main() {
  let test = example()
  println!("show dataframe: {:?}", test);

}

fn example() -> PolarsResult<DataFrame> {
 let df = df!(
     "date" => ["2020-08-21", "2020-08-21", "2020-08-22", "2020-08-23", "2020-08-22"],
     "temp" => [20, 10, 7, 9, 1],
     "rain" => [0.2, 0.1, 0.3, 0.1, 0.01]
 )?;

 df.lazy()
 .group_by([col("date")])
 .agg([
     col("rain").min().alias("min_rain"),
     col("rain").sum().alias("sum_rain"),
     col("rain").quantile(lit(0.5), QuantileMethod::Nearest).alias("median_rain"),
 ])
 .sort(["date"], Default::default())
 .collect()
}



N.B: Cargo.toml
[dependencies]
arrow = "53.2.0"
polars-lazy = "0.44.2"


And as a side note, don't expect the Rust documentation of polars to be all that good or up to date, the crate is "just a dump of the internals", i.e. the Python library is the product, the Rust crate is just a byproduct.

good to know || cheers. wouldn't it make sense to release a cleansed version (even if it's a byproduct) of the documentation as users are purely mislead and may spend lots of time to find errors which is inherent to polars documentation? Many thanks for your advice as I fixed the error after reading it independently of your detailed answer that I would also read to learn something new, potentially.

wouldn't it make sense to release a cleansed version – and who do you propose does the cleaning up? Rust documentation simply isn't a priority for the polars devs. Neither is direct usability of the Rust crate. The intended way to use polars currently is through Python. The alternative to the status quo is no Rust documentation or no polars Rust crate as the resources simply aren't there. Of course you're free to make a PR and it probably (I'm only guessing but can't see a reason why not) would get merged. (1/2)

Issues on the other hand in my experience are going to be closed as "won't fix". (2/2)

It's entirely on you to use a development (v0.*) library and expect it or it's documentation to be production quality.

It's a little hard to tell, but the "arrow" crate used in the example is a renamed import of polars-arrow, not the arrow crate (see the dependencies in the Cargo.toml):

[dependencies.arrow]
default-features = false
features = ["compute_aggregate", "compute_arithmetics", "compute_bitwise", "compute_boolean", "compute_boolean_kleene", "compute_cast", "compute_comparison"]
package = "polars-arrow"
version = "0.44.2"


And it feels a little like stating the obvious, but to use polars_core you'll have to add polars-core to your dependencies.
So you should remove arrow = "53.2.0" from your dependencies and instead add:
polars-core = "0.44.2"
arrow = { version = "0.44.2", package = "polars-arrow" }


All things being equal, my solution has consisted of:
use polars_arrow::legacy::prelude::*;

in addition to an amendment of Cargo.toml:
[dependencies]
polars-arrow = "0.44.2"
polars-core = "0.44.2"
polars-lazy = "0.44.2"

